# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined after AJAX request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

When I run my code I'm getting an error:

> cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

After AJAX success I call this function. Pleass help me.

```
var model = response;
var row = $("#tblGet tr:last-child").clone(true);
$("#tblGet tr").not($("#tblGet tr:first-child")).remove();

$.each(model.NcdexClass, function() {
  var ncdex = this;    
  $("td", row).eq(0).html(ncdex.script);
  $("td", row).eq(1).html(ncdex.expiryDate);
  $("td", row).eq(2).html(ncdex.measure);
  $("td", row).eq(3).html(ncdex.ltp);
  $("#tblGet").append(row);
  row = $("#tblGet tr:last-child").clone(true);
});
```

Comment: can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: sorry i cant because data coming from backend...

Comment: What do you try to achieve with this $("td", row)?

Comment: creating rows from database table...

Comment: I wonder `$.each(model.NcdexClass, function () {` is of array type. Could you add some extra info on the `model.NcdexClass`?

Comment: Please show the entire `$.ajax` call, not just the function body.

Comment: that is class which is backend developed for binding data to table

Comment: $.ajax({
                    url: "ncdex.aspx/topGainer",
                    data: '{}',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });

            }  ) ;

Comment: Thx, but please do it using [Edit Question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49938389/edit) so you can format the code properly and the question itself is complete instead of depending on comments.